# Rails table doesn't exist after create model from existing table

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, models

I had an existing table named boss_name and I would like to create a rails model for it.

I used "rails generate bossname" to created the model and added the 
self.table_name = "boss_name"
inside the class.

After the model had been successfully generated, I tried to start up rails console and trying to query the table.

Bossname.first give me the first value from boss_name table without problem.

rails console worked fine but when I'm running rspec for bossname_spec.rb, I had error which say "Bossname(Table doesn't exist)".

I hope anyone can tell me why it work for rails console and doesn't work for the application. Any hint on how to make it work on the application too is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you run your migration on test environment too? `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: I mentioned I had an existing table which is existed before I create the model.
For this case do I need to do the migration too?

Comment: This is not what your error mentions: `Bossname(Table doesn't exist)`. Note that your table can exist in development database (used when you call `rails console`), but not in your test database (which is used by `rspec`).

Comment: mdemolin> Thanks! It is exactly what you pointed out. They manually created the table for development database but they didn't created the same table for the test database!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That indicates that the `boss_name` table exists in your development database, but not in your test database. You can copy your current development database schema into your test database like this:

```
rake db:schema:dump
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup
```